# Does testing in android device will reduce it's life?

Tags: debug

I am an android developer. Using my moto g first gen for testing my applications. I connect the device to laptop for 12 hrs per day. Now i am planning to buy s4. Will it reduce my device's life?

Answer (score 0):

*Ideally* the charging circuits should disconnect trickle current to the battery once is is completed charging, but even sitting on a charger all day, it will continually be topped off even if not.

These batteries will maintain their best lifecycle when used between 20% and 80%, however the decrease in capacity will be very minimal over time, not much more then using it in its regular cycle.